# yarn server with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I am trying to start up an server that has:

- a mongodb container
- a backend container
- a client container

Both server containers require me to run `yarn start` at the end. However, when I run this in the dockerfile the image never stops being built as the `yarn start` command technically never stops running.

The client requires the backend to be up already, and the backend requires the mongodb db instance to be up.

How do I get this server running in docker compose?

Here is my backend dockerfile

```
 FROM node:12-alpine
 
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY ./server /app
 
 WORKDIR /app/server
 RUN yarn
 RUN yarn start
```

It really does work until I get to yarn start (Which I should probably run in the docker-compose as it needs to mongodb container to be running. I just don't know how to run this in the `docker-compose.yml`, or force the client to wait for this command to be run before running its own `yarn start`).

Comment: yarn start should be the CMD (what runs when you start a container) and not a RUN command (which is run when creating the image used to satrt a container later)

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai
If you submit this as an answer I can accept it.
I am a bit green with docker and docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn start` should be the `CMD` of your docker image (I.e what is run when you start a container) and not a `RUN` command (which is run when creating the image used to satrt a container later)

From your exemple, something like this should be better:

```
 FROM node:12-alpine
 
 WORKDIR /app
 COPY ./server /app
 
 WORKDIR /app/server
 RUN yarn
 CMD yarn start
```